# Convert array of int (decimal equivalent to a character in ASCII) to a string in C language

Tags: c, arrays, string, ascii

I am trying to convert an array of integers to a string 
These integers are equivalent to a character in ASCII table 
For example

```
int num[5] = {104, 101, 108, 108, 111} //hello
```

Then save it to

```
char *text
```

So that if do this (I'm coding in arduino)

```
Serial.print(text);
```

The output would be

```
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

```
int i;
int length = sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[0]);

/* copy values */
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    text[i] = (char) num[i];

/* null terminate */
text[length] = 0;
```

Comment: Unless the C compiler for arduino is different from ansi C compilers, you should type cast the int to a char: `text[i] = (char)num[i];`

Comment: I got nothing. It's just blank. I even tried what Barzee suggested. Any other ideas?